# Question On Time Dependent Workflow

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have created time dependent workflow for field update with Condition

```
If date>=today
```

Suppose if I update the field today then Time Base workflow logs shows that it will run 9/26/2016 12:00 AM.

My question is Date 12:00 AM is already passed then how will the TimeBbased workflow update the records.

Comment: Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow on the organization’s time zone, not the user’s. Can you check the Org's timezone?

Comment: (GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles) its org time zone and my logs showing schedule date **9/27/2016 12:00 AM**

Comment: PDT is now 12:11 AM now, so it should get executed. Can you still see pending action in time based workflow monitoring queue?

Comment: That's great. I am putting this as an answer. so that some one who face the same issue can be benefited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

> Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow on the organization’s time
>   zone, not the user’s. Users in different time zones might see
>   differences in behavior.